# slice container with O(1) constructor from iterable begin and end

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

I have a forward iterator. I want a simple iterable container which wraps it and exposes begin() and end().
I.E.

```
template <typename C>
void use_container(C c) {
  std::cout << c.begin();
}
int main() {
std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5,5};
auto begin_ = v.begin();
auto end_ = begin + 5;
use_container(/*create a container using the `begin_` and `end_` variables*/); 
return 0;
}
```

Is there such a std wrapper?

Comment: sorry, added it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're after. You already have such a container class, vector...

Comment: This is part of the reason the standard algorithms take a pair of iterators instead of a container as input, so you don't have to do this.

Comment: A sometimes used workaround is `template<typename T> struct iterator_pair { T first, last; T begin() const { return first; } T end() { return last; } };` `use_container(iterator_pair<std::vector<int>::iterator>{ begin, end })` (which is good enough for range-based for loops)

Comment: yes, @Artyer , this is exactly the implementation i wanted. i just wondered if there is a standard solution. I guess  there isn't a need as in std everything takes a begin and end arguments. still, im happy its added in cpp20, and it makes sense imo that i came across code that didn't follow this convention, and rather took as argument a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++20 added this with [`std::ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange).  For example the following will call `use_container` with a range that is a view over part of `v`:

```
use_container(std::ranges::subrange{begin_, end_});
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1626fc4f1a071497)

Comment: thanks, so i guess that means it isn't available in cpp17?

Comment: @NimrodFiat Correct, this functionality doesn't exist in the standard library prior to C++20.  The standard pattern prior to that was to just pass pairs of iterators around.